# Insert React Component to Google maps info window

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, google-maps

i've create a google maps with multiple markers. Now i want to add a content for each marker. It works fine if i do code all in strings but there's an issue loading react elements inside that string.

In this project we use IconUiKit to display icons. The goal is to add a pin icon inside the infowindow.

If seen a very similar question to mine here => [How to use a react component for showing Google Maps InfoWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55411539/how-to-use-a-react-component-for-showing-google-maps-infowindow). Unfortunately ReactDOMServer.renderToString() returns the error that ReactDOMServer could not be found.

```
private setMarkers(map: any): any {
  const {stores} = this.state;
  const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    maxWidth: 400
  });
  for (let i = 0; i < stores.length; i++) {  
    if (google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK === 'OK' && stores[i].store.address && 
       (Number(stores[i].store.address.latitude) !== undefined) && 
       Number(stores[i].store.address.longitude)) {
      let lat = stores[i].store.address.latitude !== undefined ? stores[i].store.address.latitude : 0;
      let lng = stores[i].store.address.longitude !== undefined ? stores[i].store.address.longitude : 0;
      let pos = lat && lng ? new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng) : {lat: 0, lng: 0};

      let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: pos
      });

      let projectInfo = [] as string[];
      stores[i].projects.forEach(project => {
        projectInfo.push(
          `<p><b>${project.projectNo}</b></p>` +
          '<p>Attribution: Uluru,' + 
            '<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">' +
              'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru' + 
            '</a>' +
          '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>' +
          '<a class="uk-button uk-button-grey uk-button-register uk-width-1-1 uk-text-uppercase" href="/">' +
            '<span>' +
              'Project Details' +
            '</span>' +
          '</a>'
        );
      });
      let icon = <IconUikit icon="gear" wrap={true}/>;
      console.log(icon.toString());

      let contentString = 
        '<div class="maps-tooltip">' +
          '<div class="uk-grid">' +
            '<div class="uk-width-1-4">' +
              `<img src="${stores[i].store.imageUrl}" class="uk-width-1-1"/>` +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="uk-width-3-4">' +
              `<p><b class="fr-color-black">${stores[i].store.address.name1}</b></p>` +
               /// HERE IS THE COMPONENT
              ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<IconUikit icon="gear" wrap={true}/>) +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="uk-width-1-1">' +
              `${projectInfo.toString()}` +
            '</div>' +
          '</div>' +
        '</div>';

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setOptions({
          content: contentString,
        });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!

ReactDomServer is part of @types/react-dom. Instead of calling ReactDomServer.renderToString() import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'; and just use renderToString().toString().

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct from Marlon Berdefy. Just to elaborate on it a bit more with an example:

This is using Google maps InfoWindow component. In the content of the InfoWindow, you need give it a string. By assigning the component using renderToString, you can add it to your content by wrapping it in brackets: ${ButtonToString}

`
import { Button } from 'rsuite';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';

const ButtonToString = renderToString(Register).toString()

```
let marker;
let content;
// The marker, positioned at Uluru
for(let i = 0; i < host.length; i++) {
  const markerPosition = { lat: host[i].lat, lng: host[i].lng };
  marker = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
    map: map,
    position: markerPosition,
    title: host[i].foodType,
  });

  content = 
  `<div className="flex flex-col text-gray-600">` +
    `<div className="text-lg font-bsold">${host[i].foodType}</div>` +
    `<div className="mt-2">` +
      `<div className="flex items-center">` +
        `<span>${host[i].description}</span>` +
      `</div>` +
      `<div className="flex items-center mt-1">` +
        `<div>Guest spots left: <span className="font-bold">${host[i].guestSpotsLeft}</span></div>` +
      `</div>` +
      `<div className="flex items-center mt-1">` +
        `<div className="font-bold">$${host[i].price} per person</div>` +
      `</div>` +
    `</div>` +
    `<div className='flex justify-end'>` +
      `${ButtonToString}` +
    `</div>` +
  `</div>`
```

`