# Populating Google Maps infowindow with React renderToString

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-dom

I am building a GoogleMaps Polygon widget in React JS and want to populate the infowindow with a react component because I need some more complex HTML hierarchy, adding a button in it. I looked on StackOverflow because I wasn't sure how to get the innerHTML of a React component and found this:

[How to use a react component for showing Google Maps InfoWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55411539/how-to-use-a-react-component-for-showing-google-maps-infowindow)

But after implementing I am getting an error on the renderToString function every first time a Polygon is being clicked, see below.

**Does anybody have any idea of what might be causing this?**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrentStack' of undefined
   at pushCurrentDebugStack (react-dom-server.browser.development.js:2974)
   at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (react-dom-server.browser.development.js:3683)
   at Object.renderToString (react-dom-server.browser.development.js:4297)
   at GoogleMapsContainer.<anonymous> (GoogleMapsContainer.tsx:319)
```

The way I have implemented it is by defining the React component and getting the innerHTML of it and feeding it to the Google Maps InfoWindow object as per below:

```
interface InfoWindowProps {
    className: string;
    onClickButtonLabel: string;
    onClickAction:ListActionValue;
    mxObject: ObjectItem;

}
const InfoWindowContent = (props:InfoWindowProps) => {
    
    return (<button className={props.className}>
        <span className={"glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"}>
        </span>      
        <text style={{marginLeft:"4px"}}>
            {props.onClickButtonLabel}
        </text>
    </button>)
};
maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', ( () => { 
    // infowindow object is loaded into DOM async via Google, hence need to target the domready event
    const infoWindowContent = InfoWindowContent(infoWindowProps);
    const infoWindowContentString = renderToString(infoWindowContent);

    infowindow.setContent(
        infoWindowName + '<br><br>' + infoWindowContentString
    )

}).bind(this));
```

Comment: I wrapped renderToString in a Promise which helped and made sure the error is gone, but still the first time it doesn't load properly... Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you find solution to this, please? I have the same problem.

Comment: Hi Matej, yes I found a solution. Which React Google Maps library do you use? I switched to @react-google-maps/api which has a InfoWindow component by itself. I extended that class to facilitate my needs without the need for renderToString